# Kafka spring integration authorization with sasl

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, jaas, sasl

I am trying to connect to kafka server via spring integration module with SASL config and get error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set

but when I construct simple consumer and poll messages everything works fine. Can someone tell me how to turn off JAAS authorization or connect via it properly.
Here is my [KafkaConfig.java](https://gist.github.com/YaRuliY/123a0bc65a1cc64fc7cc86963ab3a410)
and [SaslConfiguration.java](https://gist.github.com/YaRuliY/5dd64284a1bb0ccd2044d1dc4c3d9b4c). Thanks for answer!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve], meaning the code itself, not links

Comment: If you want to turn it off, why do you still have `SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG` set for SASL?

Comment: I wanna turn off JAAS, not SASL

Comment: I don't think you can... JAAS is required for SASL authorization

Comment: Thanks, did not know. Maybe you can suggest how I can correct authorize with Sprign Intergation, because when I construct consumer directly https://gist.github.com/YaRuliY/39bb0d4066c833cc456899e6336e0155 all works

Comment: I can't tell how these files are used if you just link to gists. And I'm not familiar with Spring enough to say how you can config it

Answer (score 1):

There is a `KafkaConsumerFactory` which simply can accept the same set of properties you are mentioning in you gist: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_receiving_messages